# Grafico feito com imperfeição Javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Galera fiz um plano cartesiano normal aqui num canvas, mas to com um problema, o gráfico não está perfeitamente centralizado e isso está me incomodando um bocado, eu sei q posso mudar a posição manualmente em código, mas a questão é: Por que o gráfico está descentralizado?

Eis o código JS:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var contex = document.getElementById("grafico").getContext("2d");
    contex.moveTo(0, document.getElementById("grafico").clientHeight/2);
    contex.lineTo(document.getElementById("grafico").clientWidth, document.getElementById("grafico").clientHeight/2);
    contex.moveTo(document.getElementById("grafico").clientWidth/2, 0);
    contex.lineTo(document.getElementById("grafico").clientWidth/2, document.getElementById("grafico").clientHeight);
    contex.stroke();
}
```

nesse código eu pego a altura dividida por 2 e a largura tbm, eu ja tentei tanto com o client quando com o offset e ambos apresentam a mesma imprecisão. Por que isso acontece? Obrigado

Eu testei usando os valores brutos colocando eles diretamente na função e ai funcionou certinho, a questão é, por que quando puxo da imprecisão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O ideal seria usar a propriedade `width` e `height` em vez de `clientWidth` e `clientHeight`:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var contex = document.getElementById("grafico").getContext("2d");
    contex.moveTo(0, document.getElementById("grafico").height/2);
    contex.lineTo(document.getElementById("grafico").width,
       document.getElementById("grafico").height/2);
    contex.moveTo(document.getElementById("grafico").width/2, 0);
    contex.lineTo(document.getElementById("grafico").width/2,
       document.getElementById("grafico").height);
    contex.stroke();
}
```

As propriedades `clientWidth` e `clientHeight` dependendo do browser incluem o padding do elemento, e são originalmente [implementaçoes da MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533563(VS.85).aspx).

Veja mais detalhes sobre o **[`clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth)** e o **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** na MDN.